# Transform date to timestamp python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have an particular issue, I have a Dataframe with 2 columns, one its `date_x` and the other its `timestamp` which its the `hour:min:sec`, so Im trying to transform the `timestamp` column into a Unix timestamp.

The thing that I've tried its this:

```
df.timestamp = df.timestamp.apply(lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S").timestamp())
```

But the point its that I need not only the `hour,min,second`. The correct format would be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` but I dont know how to include the `date` column because it would be `date_x` + `timestamp`.

Comment: Try strftime. ``datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")``

Comment: @ShwetaChandel the point its i need to get the info from cols = date_x + timestamp in order to get this format: date_x(YYYY-MM-dd) + timestamp(H-M-S) but i dont know how to do it properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert column to timedeltas and add to `DatetimeIndex`, last convert to unix timestamp:

```
print (df)
           timestamp
2018-02-02  17:01:15
2018-02-02  17:01:18
2018-02-02  17:01:24
2018-02-02  08:32:57
2018-02-02  08:33:02
2018-02-02  08:33:08

arr = (df.index + pd.to_timedelta(df.timestamp)).values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 6
print (arr)
[1517590875000 1517590878000 1517590884000 1517560377000 1517560382000
 1517560388000]
```

Comment: This works! but adds me tons of zeros! 
array([1517590875000000000, 1517590878000000000, 1517590884000000000, ...,
       1517560377000000000, 1517560382000000000, 1517560388000000000],
      dtype=int64)

Comment: @Peter - not missing `// 10 ** 6` ?

Comment: Wops! yes you are right! That its the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```py
pd.to_datetime(df.index.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") +' '+ df.timestamp).values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 6
```

First change index into str format using `strftime("%Y/%m/%d")` to join `date` and `timestamp` columns
then convert into datetime by [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime)
and last convert to `int64` for timestamp

Comment: seems nice, but the date_x its my index col so cant do df.date_x!

Comment: use `df.index` instead `df.date_x + ...`

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'str'
and the type its dtype('<M8[ns]')

Comment: `>>> pd.to_datetime(df.index.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") +' '+ df.a).values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 6` convert it first to str formate

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it